# Adding name to the list if it doesn't exist

Tags: bash

I have a simple script that checks if the name exists on the list and if not, it adds it, but I am having problems as the loop never stops!

I have a list with names like this:

> name1
>
> name2
>
> name3

the name of the list is names.txt

```
b=$1
FILE=names.txt
while read F ; do
    if [ "$b" != "$F" ]
    then
        echo "$b" >> names.txt
        /home/tests/emailSend.sh
    fi
done < $FILE
```

All I want to do is, when I run the script, I want to check if the name is on the list, if it is, than nothing will happen, if it is not, than I want to add the name to the list and send an email!

If I run the script like it is, it just never ends, and adds the same name on the list!

Comment: Right now it looks like you're inconsistent between `$a` and `$b`, but that's not your root cause. See answer below.

Comment: That was a typo! Edited the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently loop through the list and add the name if any name on the list doesn't match the input. It looks like you want to match if *ALL* names do not match.

```
b=$1
FILE=names.txt
MATCHED=false
while read F ; do
  if [ "$b" = "$F" ]
  then
    MATCHED=true
    break
  fi
done < $FILE

# Now check MATCHED
if ! $MATCHED
then
  echo "$b" >> names.txt
  /home/tests/emailSend.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to loop through the file, just use `grep -vx` like this:

```
grep -xFqv "$1" names.txt && echo "$1" >> names.txt
```

Comment: You'll want to specify `-x` so it matches the whole line; otherwise you'll match if the name appears anywhere within the line.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
sort -u <(echo $1) names.txt > temp; mv temp names.txt
```

Comment: Nifty! Is there a way to use the return value or a diff result to trigger an action (`emailSend.sh` in the question)?

Comment: Missed the $1. Check the answer by anubhava, `grep -v ... && do other things if grep found no matches`